# New Relic alternative for MONO?

Tags: performance, mono, monitoring, saas

I have a bunch of mono based servers running on heroku. I wish to have something like New Relic, but this is not compatible with MONO.

Is there an alternative that I could use?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not an alternative but, I detail how you can get the web requests agent working under mono in this blog post:
[Getting NewRelic monitoring working on Mono .Net Web Apps](http://www.thomasvjames.com/2012/07/getting-newrelic-monitoring-working-on-mono-net-web-apps/)

1. Grab the installer for either x86/x64
2. Using msiexec on a windows box extract the contents using an administrator install (msiexec /a )
3. Copy the GAC dlls into your application’s bin
4. Copy the newrelic.xml to newrelic.config in your application
5. Add a httpModule reference to "NewRelic.Agent.Core.Tracer.Web.NewRelicHttpModule, NewRelic.Agent.Core" in your web.config file.
6. Edit the newrelic.config file and supply your license key
7. Deploy & watch those stats roll in

Comment: Are you still using this approach? I have tried to get something similar up and running with the latest NewRelic Agent, but I am stuck with the empty app dashboard - no transactions or metrics show up, even when I manually try to send them via the AgentApi. Maybe this is not possible anymore?

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I've looked at doing this. I haven't really revisited it since.